# How can I add new languages to Microsoft Office's spellcheck?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, spell-check, language-pack

How can I add new languages to Microsoft Office's spell check?  I've Googled around a bit, but it's not clear to me.

In particular, I'd like to be able to add Polish spell checking.  Is this something I can download or purchase from somewhere on Microsoft's website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Check spelling and grammar in another language](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA102488711033.aspx)** (Microsoft Office 2007)
or the
**[corresponding page for Microsoft Office 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/check-spelling-and-grammar-in-a-different-language-HA010354780.aspx?CTT=1)**.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the [Office Language Pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suites/FX102113661033.aspx?pid=CL101732621033) suitable for your language of choice. Which includes both languages changes to the interface (which you can enable or disable) and, the important to your case, language proofing tools.

You can alternatively purchase Multi-Language versions of Microsoft Office which already include several language packs.

Answer (score 2):

[Proofing Tools 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office-2003-resource-kit/installing-proofing-tools-HA001140218.aspx) could be used on Microsoft Word 2003 and 2007. It cannot be installed on 2010.

A proofing tool for 2010 is supposedly "coming soon".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - "Office Language Pack 2010", for example for German, seems to be available in [Microsoft's online store](http://www7.buyoffice.microsoft.com/emea1/default.aspx?country_id=DE)... or was that only added since you answered two months ago?

Answer (score 0):

It varies on different versions, assuming 2007 here.

Go to the Review pane then select "Set Language"

[image]

(It is very similar in 2003, if you want a screenshot, I need to try and find a machine with it on.)

Comment: Setting the language of the document is different than having spellcheck be available in that language

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected Polish as the document language?

In Word 2007:

'Ctrl + A' to select the whole document then click the 'Language' button in the status bar and select 'Polish'.

[image]

You can make this the default language by clicking the 'Default' button.

If Polish is not listed . Open 'Microsoft Office 2007 Language Settings' (in the 'MS Office 2007 > MS Office Tools' folder in the Start menu) and add Polish from the list of available editing languages.

Comment: Yes, I have, but setting the language of the document is different than having spellcheck be available in that language.

Comment: Try adding Polish in 'Microsoft Office 2007 Language Settings'