# How to add a language dictionary to Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, language, spell-check

I am running a UK version of Word 2007 (from Office 2007 Ultimate) on Windows 7. I would like to proofread my document in Italian. To do this I click `Review | Proofing | Set language` and choose `Italian (Italy)` from the list which changes the document language. However, when I click on the `Spelling & Grammar` button, the only languages available to check the spelling are various localized versions of English, French, and Spanish (Italian is missing). How do I go about adding Italian to the list?

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/44511/how-can-i-add-new-languages-to-microsoft-offices-spellcheck) answers my question except for the Office 2007 is now out of date and the spellcheck dictionary I need is no longer being provided on Microsoft's site as a result of this.

Comment: Have you installed the Italian language pack?

Comment: Where do I get it from. Can I install it from Word 2007 or do I need to go to a special site and get it from there? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add new languages to Microsoft Office's spellcheck?](http://superuser.com/questions/44511/how-can-i-add-new-languages-to-microsoft-offices-spellcheck).

Comment: Since Office 2007 has been discontinued, installing a language pack for it, is not possible. The good news you only need an interface pack, again I found this information within 20 seconds of research, [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-language-interface-pack-LIP-downloads-d63007c2-e8ae-41fd-8bfb-fce2857010e1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).  Of course further prodding indicates Italian requires a language pack to do what you want.  So while this is a duplicate of an existing question, and the answer is correct, its not possible due to the age of the software.

Comment: So basically I'm stuck with it unless I upgrade to a newer version. That sucks.

Answer (score -1):

Some links from the web say they are no longer available yet some will still connect, for office 2007 language packs you may have to, language service packs and translator packs for 2007, I just downloaded the Microsoft Translator Installer For Office2007 today 06/02/2019 from 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5780

also I just re-downloaded the office 2007 language pack sp 1
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14813

and looking for a valid link to sp2 and sp3
You may have to find the primary language pack for the language you wish to install from a third party vendor such as amazon.